# htaccess block pages based on query string for crawlers

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to block some specific pages from being indexed / accessed by Google. This pages have a GET parameter in common and I would like to redirect bots to the equivalent page without the GET parameter.

Example - page to block for crawlers:

mydomain.com/my-page/?module=aaa

Should be blocked based on the presence of module= and redirected permanently to

mydomain.com/my-page/

I know that canonical can spare me the trouble of doing this but the problem is that those urls are already in the Google Index and I'd like to accelerate their removal. I have already added a noindex tag one month ago and I still see results in google search. It is also affecting my crawl credit.

What I wanted to try out is the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} module=
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (googlebot|bingbot|Baiduspider) [NC]
```

Is this correct?

What should I add for the final redirection?

It's a tricky thing to do so before implementing anything I'd like to make sure it's the right thing to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} module= [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (googlebot|bingbot|Baiduspider) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R=301]
```

Last `?` in `%{REQUEST_URI}?` will remove previous query string.

Comment: thanks! the query string & user agent work but the redirection in the end goes to the index.php page of my site (home page), it doesn't lead me to the equivalent page without the query string.

Comment: Make sure this your **topmost** rule. Place it just below `RewriteEngine On` line and completely clear your browser cache.

Comment: you're right, there was another condition above, thanks!